# Appending Input fields to form. Post value not working Jquery Codeigniter PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to insert multiple hidden input fields with a value from another input field.

HTML

```
<?php echo form_open('controller/submit_now'); ?>
<div id="FormWrapper"></div>
<button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

FormWrapper is inside the form. I tried adding an input inside and the post value is working. The valueFromOtherInput also has value.

```
$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    name: 'valueFromInputFields[]',
    value:$('#valueFromOtherInput').val()
}).appendTo('#FormWrapper');
```

But the post value is not there when I submit the form. It seems that the name of the form is not working?

Function

```
print_r($this->input->post());
```

Comment: Add your form submit code

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, your input should be wrapped in the <form> (not in the <div>) in order to be submitted

Comment: I mentioned in the question that it's wrapped in form and its working when I put static input field in that div.

Comment: might be your name attribute caused an issue **name: 'valueFromInputFields[]'** remove bracketes **[]** than try hope it'll work

Comment: @Curiousdev No good, the input field is added and the value is there, But when I submit the form, the post value is not there

Comment: I can't figure out the problem, the input field is showing but its name attribute might not be there?

Comment: @Curiousdev it's a valid notation to use square brackets in the name. All the input with the same name will be posted togheter in an array.

Comment: @LelioFaieta Hi, do you have any idea what's the problem with this?